# Assessing significance of correlation

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

I have two variables, and I can calculate e.g. the Pearson correlation between them, but I would like to know something analogous to what a t-test would give me (i.e. some notion of how significant the correlation is).

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Use the Fisher Transformation or a t-test based on a scaled tangent tranformation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Determining_significance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can get a $p$-value for testing the null hypothesis that the Pearson correlation is zero. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_correlation#Inference.

Comment: For anyone else interested: this can be done in R with `cor.test()`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, [this beautiful paper](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/crism/research/2005/05-15/05-15wv1.pdf) (a bit technical/mathsy, so beware) allows you to test for *any* correlation (not just $\rho=0$) using a Non-informative Bayesian Decision Theoretic approach.